# JSON values exists?

Tags: json

I want to build a script which get s a JSON and manipulates it.
I have one problem, i don't know how to check if a certain value exists, for example:

i get this JSON when doing action 1:

```
{
 "url": "http://zuberi.me",
 "top": "true"
}
```

and when i do action 2:

```
{
 "url": "http://zuberi.me",
 "top": "true",
 "copy": "false"
}
```

so i want to check if "copy" is exists in the JSON response i get...

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to check before or after the JSON text is evaluated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof(json.copy) === 'boolean') {
```

Answer (score 3):

A javascript implementation:

```
var json1 = { "url": "http://zuberi.me",
              "top": "true",
              "copy": "false" },

json2 = { "url": "http://zuberi.me",
          "top": "true" };

json1.hasOwnProperty('copy'); // true
json2.hasOwnProperty('copy'); // false
```

Comment: @Dor, yes it does. You should know that you ended up choosing the answer that is most unreliable (it clearly is type-specific, so won't work for strings, or numbers, or objects etc.). Only my and Tomalak's answers are complete solutions, and they differ only in the prototype chain of the objects, which probably won't affect you anyway. I challenge you to find a javascript console in which the above code behaves differently than I described...

Comment: @Tomalak :) I think the only way to deal with them is to smile and walk away.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your JSON string is already converted to a JavaScript object:

```
if ("copy" in json) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've never known this syntax. I always do `if(json.copy = undefined) {...}`.

Comment: @Dor: Please show a small but complete code sample that's failing.

Comment: `in` is an ECMAScript Third Edition standard operator, though not supported by IE before 5.5. It is IMO cleaner and more explicit than an `!==undefined` or `typeof()!=='undefined'` test (which can be confused if there's a property there but set to the `undefined` value. (Not a problem with JSON though as there is no `undefined` value in JSON.)

Comment: @boince: I consider *"not supported by IE before 5.5"* arcane knowledge by now. :) But otherwise, I agree. I think it's a lot more elegant and idiomatic than comparing to `undefined`.

Comment: @bobince `undefined` in JSON is the same as "good bye" in Klingon, just not said in the first place :)